# Set context root in Spring Boot web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, contextroot

Hello I am building a web application in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.

I need to set the context root of the app which I have set like this:

```
@GetMapping ("/CautareTelefonMail/" )
public String getHello() {

return "index" ;
}



@PostMapping("/")
public String postDbRequest(@RequestParam(name="text2",required = false)String telefon, Model model, @RequestParam(name="email",required = false)String email) throws Exception {

   /// code that does the searching in the database
    
   return "index";
}
```

This way when I access `http://localhost:8080/CautareTelefonMail/` it shows me the form and it works. But when I get the results in the table the address in the address bar is just `http://localhost:8080`. I need it to be `http://localhost:8080/CautareTelefonMail/`.

How can I do this ?

This is what I`ve tried:

```
@PostMapping("/CautareTelefonMail")
public String postDbRequest(@Reques...etc.
```

But when I modify it like this it does not return anything it returns the error page.

Can please someone give me an ideea how to do it ? Also in the html in the form I have at `action="/"`

Comment: set `server.servlet.context-path=/CautareTelefonMail` then remove it from your controller(s) and leave only the base path.

Comment: And in my forms at action what do I put - action="/CautareTelefonMail/index" or action="/index" ? Thanks

Comment: Your forms should have the full (or a relative path but you are safer with a full one).

Comment: Still not working it gives me 404 page

Comment: Your controller should now have `/` and not the full parameter. ALso why is that URL so important?